# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component (Axios request)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, code-cleanup

I have a login form with a submit button that trigger **handleSubmit** function, in this function i am doing my axios stuff

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {  
     e.preventDefault();
     //action creator
     loginUser(loginData)
}
```

My Redux action creator:

```
export const loginUser = (loginData) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.post('/signin', loginData)
        .then(res => {
            let FBIdToken = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
            localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', FBIdToken);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response ?  err.response.data : {}
            });
         })
 }
```

Now after unmounting the login component i get that error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I know what is my problem is , i need to clean up my axios request, How to clean axios request in my case??

Comment: I'd say you probably have a `setState` somewhere in your `login` component that's fired after umnounting.

Comment: Is it happening when the request is successful or not ? And what state is being updated the login component state ?

Comment: @k-wasilewski  yes so why i am asking for a cleanup, all state managed by redux, the state fragment here is errors

Comment: @h1b9b yes the resquest is successful and the token put in the right place in the loacal storage

Comment: Where does the `history` object on `loginUser` comes from ?

Comment: @h1b9b sorry it is not related to the problem i think, i removed it from the question

Comment: @CodeEagle ok, so it would be easier to help if you provided us your complete code of `index.js` :)